# scroll moble navigation on a fixed header

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using meanmenu jquery plugin to display navigation for mobile devices and have a fixed header.  The problem is the links on the website aren't clickable with the following code.  The navigation does drop-down past the full screen size on mobile devices. I think height:100% is causing the issue where links are not clickable.

```
#headercontainer {
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    z-index:10;
    overflow-y:auto;
    height:100%;
}
```

I tried the following and the links are clickable but the navigation is constricted to size of the mobile screen and additional navigation items are cutoff.

```
#headercontainer {
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    z-index:10;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height:auto;
}
```